# How to get FileInput field to work in react-admin 3.2.3

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I followed the react-admin 3.2.0 documentation about `FileInput` field (see https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#fileinput) and made a `create` Form like below:

```
export const TemplateCreate = props => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Create {...props}>
            <SimpleForm redirect="list">
                <TextInput source="id" disabled variant="outline" />
                <TextInput source="name" label="Dateiname" />
                <TextInput source="beschreibung" />
                <FileInput source="pdffile" label="PDF-Template" accept="application/pdf" >
                    <FileField source="src" title="title" />
                </FileInput>
            </SimpleForm>
        </Create>
    );
};
```

The code unfortunately results in an error during rendering:

```
> isMuiElement.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'muiName'
> of undefined
>     at isMuiElement (isMuiElement.js:3)
>     at FormControl.js:101
>     at forEachSingleChild (react.development.js:1252)
>     at traverseAllChildrenImpl (react.development.js:1145)
>     at traverseAllChildrenImpl (react.development.js:1161)
>     at traverseAllChildren (react.development.js:1226)
>     at Object.forEachChildren [as forEach] (react.development.js:1274)
>     at FormControl.js:100
>     at mountState (react-dom.development.js:16624)
>     at Object.useState (react-dom.development.js:17181)
>     at Object.useState (react.development.js:1619)
>     at FormControl (FormControl.js:94)
>     at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16260)
>     at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:18143)
>     at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:20211)
>     at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:336)
>     at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:385)
>     at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:440)
>     at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:25780)
>     at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24695)
>     at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:24671)
>     at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24270)
>     at react-dom.development.js:12199
>     at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:697)
>     at runWithPriority$2 (react-dom.development.js:12149)
>     at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:12194)
>     at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:12182)
>     at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:24439)
>     at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:27527)
>     at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:27608)
>     at Module../src/index.js (index.js:7)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
>     at fn (bootstrap:150)
>     at Object.1 (serviceWorker.js:137)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
>     at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
>     at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
>     at main.chunk.js:1
```

How to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

you may not have defined your useStyles before using it (something like that):

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
...
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    marginTop: '0em',
  },
  ...
}))
```

Comment: they are defined, otherwise it would lead to a compile error. The error I described is a runtime error.

Comment: The error is clearly not in the code that you showed.

Comment: I guess so, maybe I just used the components wrongly... I don't know, documentation ist not very detailed. I hope to get some hints on how to do a file upload in react-admin in general....

Comment: Look here: "Extending a Data Provider (Example of File Upload)" https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html

Comment: Thanks, I already implemented that in my dataProvider. The thing is that the error occurs on rendering the form, I don't even get to initiating an upload.

Comment: Perhaps you have a problem with the versions of libraries after the update? Check the package.json, delete the node_modules directory, clear the NPM/yarn cache

Answer (score 0):

`variant="outline"` is not valid.  Use `variant="outlined"`.

See https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api.

Credit to https://github.com/fzaninotto for figuring this out